# sort command- numeric sort not working on csv

Tags: sort

GNU `sort` on Linux is not giving expected results on my csv file. Can you please help to resolve the situation/ issue?

**Input file**

```
[nscruser]$ cat cemp1.txt
10,30
50,900
20,1050
```

**Objective** I need to do numeric sort on the first field for the above file

```
[nscruser]$  sort -t',' -k1 -n cemp1.txt
10,30
50,900
20,1050
```

**Expected output** But I expected the output as below as I am doing a numeric sort on first column

```
10,30
20,1050
50,900
```

Can someone please let me know why the discrepancy?

Comment: Are you on Linux? Is this GNU `sort`?

Comment: [nscruser]$ uname
Linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the man page of `sort` (from GNU coreutils 8.32),

> -k, --key=KEYDEF
> sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
>
> ...
>
> KEYDEF  is  F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]  for  start and stop position, where F is a field number and C a character position in the
> field;
> both are origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.  If neither -t nor -b is in effect,  characters  in  a
> field  are
> counted  from the beginning of the preceding whitespace.  OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options [bdfgiMhnRrV],
> which over‐
> ride global ordering options for that key.  If no key is given, use the entire line as the key.  Use --debug to diagnose
> incorrect  key
> usage.

First, you can use `--debug` as suggested,

```
$ sort -t',' -k1 -n --debug cemp1.txt
sort: text ordering performed using ‘en_IE.UTF-8’ sorting rules
sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
10,30
_____
_____
50,900
______
______
20,1050
_______
_______
```

That gives us a clue: "key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields".

As the man page says, "the stop position defaults to the line's end". So you need to add a stop position:

```
$ sort -t',' -k1,1 -n cemp1.txt
10,30
20,1050
50,900
```

Comment: This seems to be specific to GNU `sort`.  The native `sort` on BSD systems does not seem to have this quirk.

Comment: @Dario Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Thank you all for the help

Comment: I get correct sorting with the command in the original question, and I have GNU sort: `$ sort --version` output is `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.28 ...`; @user1626902, which version are you running? or maybe the sorting rules of `en_IE.UTF-8` is causing the problem. What happens if you prefix the command line with `LANG=C `

Comment: @sudodus I'm guessing you are using the `C` or `POSIX` locale.  Using `LC_ALL=C sort ...` would be the other solution to the user's issue.

Comment: ... fwiw it appears to be an issue with the numeric locale's thousands separator rather than the collation locale itself - I can reproduce the issue with `sort (GNU coreutils 8.30)` in an otherwise `C.UTF-8` locale using `LC_NUMERIC=en_US.utf8` (`decimal_point="."` ; `thousands_sep=","`) but not using `LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.utf8` (`decimal_point=","` ; `thousands_sep=" "`)

Comment: ... see also [unix sort -n -t"," gives unexpected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228968/unix-sort-n-t-gives-unexpected-result)

Comment: @Kusalananda, The command in the original question works correctly for me both with my default, `LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8` and `LC_NUMERIC=sv_SE.UTF-8` (and when I switch to `LANG=C`). I agree with you that a standard environment `C` should make it work, and now I understand that `LC_ALL=C` should be more waterproof than `LANG=C`

Comment: @Kusalananda The GNU sort seem to have no problem. The gsort works correctly under OpenBSD, Perhaps the OpenBSD default `C` locale is making it work?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to prefix your command with `LANG` or `LC_ALL` locale variables :

```
LANG=C sort -t',' -k1,1 -n cemp1.txt
```

or

```
LC_ALL=C sort -t',' -k1,1 -n cemp1.txt
```

The variable used depends on the command and/or the OS version. On HP-UX 11.31 (Unix SYSTEM 5) : `man 3C locale` extract

```
LANG                LC_MESSAGES
LC_ALL              LC_MONETARY
LC_COLLATE          LC_NUMERIC
LC_CTYPE            LC_TIME
```